Kafka Connect sink connector filter for nested json
I have a sink connector to push data from a Kafka Topic to a Snowflake DB, my problem is that i need to add a transformation to filter out certain records based on a nested json.
A typical record would look like
{
    "direction": "IN",
    "header": {
               "body_byte_count": "31",
               "body_encoding": "B8",
               "message_type": "paxremove",
               "timestamp": "1726334272"
               }
}

I need a transformation to only allow records with "message_type" = "foo"
Is this possible using Kafka Connect?

Kafka Connect generally doesn't do filtering. Kafka Streams / ksqlDB can
